# elasticsearch: NullPointerException with has_parent query

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I have a nested NullPointerException when running has_parent queries. 
Find below a sample query with the problem :

```
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "parent_type": "cluster",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to run it to find all the documents with type global. 
An example of global document :

```
     {
        "_index": "cluster",
        "_type": "global",
        "_id": "efd880791b",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "lppversion": "7.1.1.3",
          "version": "7.1.1 SP4",
          "clustername": "lgeha_cluster"
        },
        "fields": {
          "_parent": "645bb3e3da"
        }
      }
```

With the parent one :

```
{
  "_index": "cluster",
  "_type": "cluster",
  "_id": "645bb3e3da",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
     "scriptname": "ha_collector.sh"
   }
}
```

An here the mappings for global :

```
{
  "index_analyzer": "default_index",
  "search_analyzer": "default_search",
  "_parent": {
    "type": "cluster"
  },
  "_routing": {
    "required": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "lppversion": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "version": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "clustername": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

I use ruby client libray elasticsearch 1.0.1.

Here a full example of error message :

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[9JTe0ya7Q4qSvwhcBGf0DQ][cluster][4]: SearchParseException[[cluster][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"has_parent\":{\"parent_type\":\"cluster\",\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}}}}}]]]; nested: NullPointerException; }{[9JTe0ya7Q4qSvwhcBGf0DQ][cluster][3]: SearchParseException[[cluster][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"has_parent\":{\"parent_type\":\"cluster\",\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}}}}}]]]; nested: NullPointerException; }{[9JTe0ya7Q4qSvwhcBGf0DQ][cluster][2]: SearchParseException[[cluster][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"has_parent\":{\"parent_type\":\"cluster\",\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}}}}}]]]; nested: NullPointerException; }{[9JTe0ya7Q4qSvwhcBGf0DQ][cluster][1]: SearchParseException[[cluster][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"has_parent\":{\"parent_type\":\"cluster\",\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}}}}}]]]; nested: NullPointerException; }{[9JTe0ya7Q4qSvwhcBGf0DQ][cluster][0]: SearchParseException[[cluster][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"has_parent\":{\"parent_type\":\"cluster\",\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}}}}}]]]; nested: NullPointerException; }]","status":400}
```

I have this messages for all queries on all types in this index. i have another index working perfectly well with a similar mapping.

If you have ideas about it, it will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Alain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at least i understood what happened. It's not related to the types. I created a mapping for a type where the parent type doesn't exist.

```
"_parent": {
    "type": "not_exist"
  }
```

So it's what means **NullPointerException** :) Didn't found it anywhere on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change "parent_type" for "type", so, your query should look like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "type": "cluster",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```